# Taxonomy and Custom Post type order

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm a bit lost with this one.

I am trying to make a index page for my custom taxonomy which i have 99% working, however it's ignoring orderby and displaying the posts in posted date order.

```
$number_of_posts = intval(get_option('theme_number_posts_agent'));
$get_county = get_terms( 
    'new_developments', 
    array(
       'orderby'    => 'name',
       'order'      => 'ASC',
       'hide_empty' => 1,
    )
);

if(!$number_of_posts){
    $number_of_posts = 3;
}

foreach ( $get_county as $get_countys ) {
    $agents_query = array(
        'post_type'      => 'agent',
        'posts_per_page' => $number_of_posts,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'orderby'        => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'new_developments',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $get_countys
            )
        )
    );

$agent_listing_query = new WP_Query( $agents_query );

if ( $agent_listing_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $agent_listing_query->have_posts() ) :
        $agent_listing_query->the_post();
```

I have placed orderby in two places under get_terms and in the wp_query but nothing...

Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: did you read this question ? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy

Comment: hmmm ok seems, a little silly as for what i am working with it would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to order the custom taxonomy.. In codex you can give order to taxonomy by 
1) id
2) count
3) Name
4) Slug
5) term_group - No completamente implementado (avoid using)
6) None.
But there is no option for date.

I guess you can use 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/
This plugins this is best answer for you

Thank you